# issue in vector

Tags: java, vector

I am trying to add some data to vector by checking if the vector already has the data,even if vector has the data the loop is coming to else block.

```
Vector object = (Vector) listUserEvents.get(key);
Vector compareEventData = (Vector) hCompareTable.get(compareKey);

for (int i = 0; i < compareEventData.size(); i++) {
    EventData eCompare = (EventData) compareEventData.elementAt(i);
    if (object.contains(eCompare)) {
        System.out.println("in if of compare");
    } else {
        System.out.println("in else of compare");
}
```

Comment: Are they the same object (as in the same instance)? If not are equals and hashcode correcly implemented? Side note: do you need to use a Vector (vs. arraylist for example)?

Comment: Have a look at the equals method of the EventData. The contains method will only return true if two objects equal. You probably have new EventData objects, so they do not equal with the default Object.equals() method.

Comment: i have not implemented equals and hashcode

Comment: Well, then the EventData objects in both vectors are different and thus you never get into the if block.

Comment: What do the EventData objects contain? If there is anything that identifies the event you could use that to compare the objects.

Comment: Also I would prefer to use the generic `Vector<T>` version instead of the simple `Vector`, thus you will not need the type-casts.

Comment: EventData is a bean class which holds the properties of events @morja

Answer (score 1):

If the code is not behaving as you expect, it is most likely that you don't understand what `contains` is actually doing.

The `contains` method is looking for an element in the vector which the `equals` method says is equal to the argument; e.g. it is (more or less) equivalent to:

```
    boolean found = false;
    for (Object eventData : object) {
        if (eventData.equals(eCompare)) {
             found = true;
        }
    }
```

If this is giving an unexpected answer, then the likely cause is in the way that `equals` is defined (or not) for the `EventData`.  In particular, if you haven't overriden `equals`, then `EventData` could be inheriting the `equals` method from `Object`.  If it does that, then `equals` *means* "has the same object reference".  That is probably the wrong semantic for your use-case.

Comment: Here object is a vector and eCompare is a EvenData bean class,i cannot use  for (EventData e : object) ,i am trying to see if object vector has eCompare

Comment: @harqs - you are right.  There was a compilation error in my code.  Fixed now.  However, the point of my code is NOT for you to use it.  The point is to EXPLAIN to you how the `contains` method WORKS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `EventData.equals()`. Once you do this, you should also override [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).

Finally, using a `Vector` results in pretty poor computational complexity since every `contains()` check costs `O(n)`. Also, using `Vector` is usually not recommended in new code.

You would be better off using [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) instead (or, if the ordering of elements is not important, any `Set`).

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, your `EventData` seem to be different instances in both vectors. If you expect them to be equal in the sense that they contain the same information, you should compare the `EventData` objects based on a property that is identifying them. E.g.:

```
Vector<EventData> object = (Vector<EventData>) listUserEvents.get(key);
Vector<EventData> compareEventData = (Vector<EventData>) hCompareTable.get(compareKey);

for (EventData eCompare : compareEventData) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (EventData other : object) {
        if (other.getSomeProperty().equals(eCompare.getSomeProperty())) {
           found = true;
           break;
        } 
    }
    if(found){
       System.out.println("contains");
    }else {
       System.out.println("does not contain");
    }
}
```